# Using a WebSocket API with Struts 2

Tags: java, spring, struts2, websocket, tomcat7

I have a Struts2 web application running on Tomcat 7.0.43 that uses Rest and Convention plugins to map all requests. Struts tries to map all requests by itself.

JSR 356 defines server end points using annotations like

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/chat")
```

Now when the broswer tries to connect to `ws:/127.0.0.1:8080/websocket/chat`, the request fails because the Struts mapper intercepts the request.

Is there anything I can specify in the XML files, such that the request reaches the right place?

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I added

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/websocket.*?" />
```

to my Struts configuration, after which the URL /websocket/chat started reaching a 404 error.

Later I learnt that I need to configure a `ServerApplicationConfig` implementation. After doing that the websocket starts working fine but the rest of my application fails to load giving an error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Here is my class:

```
public class Socket implements ServerApplicationConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> scanned) {

        Set<ServerEndpointConfig> result = new HashSet<ServerEndpointConfig>();

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> scanned) {

        Set<Class<?>> results = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        for (Class<?> clazz : scanned) {
            results.add(clazz);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

How can I get everything to work together in Harmony?

Note: I am using Struts Spring Plugin for Dependency Injection of Spring Security.

Comment: Partitioning problems will help you get answers much faster. As you found out you can prevent struts from trying to act on certain urls after that there is currently no struts2/websocket integration. Both technologies are front facing (well front most tier on the server) and have little interaction. But combining both into a single question will reduce the audience. The answer to getting things to work in harmony is developing business logic in the service tier, which both s2 and ws will consume.

Comment: I am too facing the problem @Manu do you have any solution? Please let me know if you have. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can configure the Struts filter to exclude some URLs via regex pattern. You should add the constant in the `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="^ws://.+$"/>
```

Use [Websocket API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm#GKJIQ5) for server endpoints.

Comment: Added the constant but now the ws request leads to a 404 error. Any idea how to make it reach the chat class/to read the annotation?