# What's the * replacement in xml to indicate any string

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, struts2

I have this in my xml file: `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ws/*"/>`. In the 'value' attribute what I want to say is that I want any string.
For example, **"/ws/some_string"** where *some_string* is a string with no spaces.

I'm doing a Java web project and this is part of my struts.xml file, in order to use web sockets.

Comment: The exclude pattern is a *pattern*, e.g., a regex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20774984/573032